# Ways to register a user in an asp.net mvc website from another mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to go about creating a user in one of my asp.net mvc websites from another one, basically integrate the two sites a bit.

Site A (ASP.NET MVC 4, VS 2012) needs to take some information from a customer upon a POST action and from within that action (server side) send a POST to Site B (MVC 5, VS 2013, ASP.NET Identity 2) to create a user in it (it doesn't have to wait for the post to complete, it can fire and forget...but open to suggestions here too).  Both sites are owned and operated by myself, but exist for different purposes up until now.

I'm thinking I need to expose a controller action on Site B that will allow another Site A to POST to it the information needed to create the user.

Would it make sense to just add this as another action to my existing controller in Site B that creates user accounts, or would it make more sense to create a web api controller that handles it separately?  Are there performance differences between the two controller types?

Also, how would I secure this new endpoint/action - I'm considering generating an api key of sorts (generating and storing a GUID as a private key that they submit with the request) to verify that it is in fact Site A making the request (all over https of course), and no one else.  I only want to open this up to Site A to do, and this single action is likely as far as integrating these sites will ever go.

Any feedback would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Are the user's the same for both sites?  Is there any reason you would not integrate the sites simply by sharing the same database?

Comment: No they aren't the same, and they cannot share the same database, these really are two separate apps that I happen to own, but it's possible that one could be sold to another party at some point so they can't share any resources that way.